# I want to customize the bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, css

Is there any way to modify the bootstrap carousel. i want to give an effect where the slide will be faded in and faded out instead of sliding left to right or right to left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can modify the bootstrap carousel by overriding the CSS. Add the following `<style>` tag in your HTML page and it will fade in/out the carousel instead of sliding effect.

```
<style>
/* Fade transition for carousel items  */ 
.carousel .item {
  left: 0 !important;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .4s; /*adjust timing here */
     -moz-transition: opacity .4s;
       -o-transition: opacity .4s;
          transition: opacity .4s;
 }
.carousel-control {
       background-image: none !important; /* remove background gradients on controls */
 }
/* Fade controls with items */
.next.left,
.prev.right {
opacity: 1;
z-index: 1;
}
.active.left,
.active.right {
opacity: 0;
z-index: 2;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks brother for your answer.

I have used this code before posting this question , it's work well in every modern browser except the google chrome. I couldn't figure out why it's hapening. another thing why do i have to put this code inside of the script tag. I will be greatfull if help me out

Comment: I think your tag `<script>` is wrong. Should it not be `<style>`?

Comment: @jbutler483 thanks for pointing out the error. I am updating my code.

Comment: @HifzurRahman I have tested it on chrome its working fine at my end. could you please provide your problem case in jsfiddle? <script> tag is added mistakenly updated with <style> tag

Comment: @Wahaj Ahmed I don't know which version of the bootstrap you are using. If you are using the older version then it will work fine with your aforementioned code, but if you are in the latest version, then you have to add a little more code which will overwrite the bootstrap style..  

.carousel-inner > .item.next,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
  }
.carousel-inner > .item.prev,
 .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
  }